# Python control.matlab lsim

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to get the system response by inserting a sinusoidal input function, but the code below gives the following error:

*ValueError: Parameter T: time values must be equally spaced.*

```
from control.matlab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num = [1]
den = [1,1]
sys = tf(num,den)

t = np.arange(0,20,0.01)
w0 = 3
u = np.cos(w0*t)
y,t,x = lsim(sys, t, u)

plt.plot(t,y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Looking at the docs of [`control.matlab.lsim`](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.3/generated/control.matlab.lsim.html#control.matlab.lsim), you should swap `t` and `u`: `lsim(sys,u ,t)`

Comment: I looked at the documentation to try to implement the code but I couldn't.

Comment: What do you mean? did you try to switch the order of the inputs `t` and `u`?